# migrating from db2 Express-C to Developer version

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a backup file from db2 express-c 11.1 version and I'd like to restore it into db2 developer version (both on Windows machine). The RESTORE completed successfully and I can list the tables from the db2 command line

```
db2 list tables for schema XYZ
```

but when I'm trying to access the data I'm getting the following error message

```
SQL0551N  The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the
required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.  Authorization
ID: "DB2USER".  Operation: "SELECT". Object: "XYZ.Table1".  SQLSTATE=42501
```

I logged in as the user who RESTORE the database. WHat's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When restoring a DB2-luw database backup to a different Db2-instance , it is wise to *first* set a Db2-registry variable on the target Db2-instance *before* performing the database-restore. The account performing the Db2-restore will then be granted SECADM, DBADM, DATAACCESS, and ACCESSCTRL authorities on the restored database.

```
db2set DB2_RESTORE_GRANT_ADMIN_AUTHORITIES=on
```

More information [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.regvars.doc/doc/r0005658.html#r0005658__S_DB2_RESTORE_GRANT_ADMIN_AUTHORITIES).

Then perform the Db2-restore command.

If you have not taken this action then you can also use manual **GRANT**  statements (on database level and object level) to adjust to the new Db2-instance, but for best results you should use the registry variable above.

You can also use the **TRANSFER OWNERSHIP** statement at various levels to achieve the security model. Details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0021665.html).  This is useful when the previous owner was the Db2-instance and the restored-database is in a different Db2-instance than the backed-up-database.

Comment: I removed the restored db and executed your command and then restore it again, Now I can see the tables content from the command line, but I'm still facing some issue in Data Studio and getting the following error

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-20249, SQLSTATE=     , SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSSH200, DRIVER=3.69.56

Comment: Please don't ask *new* questions in comment threads. You have a NEW issue unrelated to the original question.  Create a new question and mark the answer as correct if it helped you.